# Getting started with Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm getting started with learning visual basic and was wondering if I should download the visual studio community or the visual studio code? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you own a Windows machine, Visual Studio Community is the best. **But only if you have a Windows machine.**

If you use some other OS like macOS you will have to use Visual Studio Code, but it is not as easy to set up.

macOS does have a Visual Studio for Mac, but it is not the same as Visual Studio for Windows. Instead, it is used for Unity3d programming and Xamarin for mobile applications.

Coming from **2 years of classroom experience**, Visual Studio Community is the **BEST** way to begin learning Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code uses .NET Core, a limited Open-Source Version of the .NET Framework. 
VS Community uses the full .NET Framework and allows you to use e.g. Windows Forms.
VS Code is more lightweight than VS Community, but for a beginner it's usually simpler to use VS Community if you just want
to learn programming. There is also more information about VS Community so I recommend you to use it.

Visual Studio Community is only available for Windows, so if you are on Linux or MacOS X you'll have to use VS Code.